# PHP Symfony no search result

Tags: php, symfony, search

I am having issues with searching, I am working on a project so that users can find delivery dates based on zipcodes. There are zipcodes from both Holland and Belgium, the Dutch zipcodes are just numbers (ex. 1000) and the Belgium ones are with a B in front of it so (ex. B1000). When I search for B1000, it shows no result.I hope you guys can help me with both of these issues. Thanks in advance.

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Entity\Nlbelevering;

class PostcodezoekerController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route ("/nlbe/levering", name="nlbelevering")
     */
    public function nlbeleveringHomepage(Request $request){
        $nlbelevering = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Nlbelevering")->findAll();

        $search = $request->get('q');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if ($search) {
            $nlbelevering = $em->createQuery('Select a FROM AppBundle:Nlbelevering a WHERE a.postcode LIKE :query')
                    ->setParameter('query', '%'.$search.'%');
        } else{
            $nlbelevering = $em->createQuery('Select a FROM AppBundle:Nlbelevering a WHERE a.postcode LIKE :query')
                    ->setParameter('query', '%'.$search.'%');
        }

        //Verwijzing naar formulier
        return $this->render('nlbe/levering/Nlbelevering.html.twig', [
            'nlbelevering' => $nlbelevering->getResult(),
            'q' => $search
        ]);
    }

}

?>
```

**Twig**

```
{% extends 'layout/default.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}NL/BE - Levering 30-33{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <style>
    .zoekformulier{

  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
    }

    </style>


    <div class= "zoekformulier">
    <form>
        <input name="q" value="{{ q }}" placeholder="Zoeken" />
        <button type="submit">Zoeken</button>
    </form>
    </div>


        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            {% if q == 0 %}
               <div class="col-md-12" style="display:none"> 
            {% else %}
                <div class="col-md-12">
            {% endif %}
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Postcode</th>
                        <th scope="col">Week 30</th>
                        <th scope="col">Week 31</th>
                        <th scope="col">Week 32</th>
                        <th scope="col">Week 33</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for postcode in nlbelevering %}
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{ postcode.postcode }}</th>
                        <td>{{ postcode.week1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ postcode.week2 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ postcode.week3 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ postcode.week4 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Postcode</th>
                        <th scope="col">Week 34</th>


        <th scope="col">Week 35</th>
                        <th scope="col">Week 36</th>
                        <th scope="col">Week 37</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for postcode in nlbelevering %}
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">{{ postcode.postcode }}</th>
                        <td>{{ postcode.week5 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ postcode.week6 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ postcode.week7 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ postcode.week8 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Search, no strict matching**

[image: Search]

**Search, no result**

[image: Search2]

Comment: What's the purpose of the `if ($search)`-statement? It seems to be doing the exact same thing regardless?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I built it for future purpose, I just programmed a part of the actual program.

Comment: also $nlbelevering seems to be a collection and in the if cases a query? Did you debugged your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of your condition: comparing a string and a 0 will return true in twig, better use this code:

```
        {% if q == "" %}
           <div class="col-md-12" style="display:none"> 
        {% else %}
            <div class="col-md-12">
        {% endif %}
```